# Postgres database upgrade from Postgresql 10 to Postgresql 12 .And currently Master Slave configured. So need steps

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, rollback, master-slave, postgresql-12

I am going to upgrade Postgresql database from Postgresql 10 to Postgresql 12. And I gave Master With 2 slave database configured.Database size is 3tb apps.so please share upgrade steps and also post upgrade what changes I have to do in new postgres 12 postgres.conf file.Also What is the easiest way to upgrade its slave database server.
So if upgrade failed how to rollback.